# 2D contour plot in python using 1D X, Y and Z variables

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

Let me begin this query by admitting that I am very new to Python. I want to create contour plot of the data in Python so as to automate the process, which otherwise can be easily carried out using Surfer. I have 1000s of such data files, and creating manually could be very tedious.
The data I'm using looks like follows, which is a dataframe with 0, 1 and 2 headers and 1,2,..279 as index:

```
     0   1         2
0     3  -1 -0.010700
1     4  -1  0.040100
2     5  -1  0.061000
3     6  -1  0.052000
4     7  -1  0.013100
..   ..  ..       ...
275  30  -9 -1.530100
276  31  -9 -1.362300
277  32  -9 -1.190200
278  33  -9 -1.083600
279  30 -10 -1.864600

[280 rows x 3 columns]
```

Here,

```
x=data[0]
y=data[1]
z=data[2]
```

As contour function pf matplotlib requires z to be a 2D array; this is where the confusion begins. Following several solutions of stackoverflow queries, I did the following:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
z=np.array(z)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
import scipy.interpolate
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='cubic')
Z=rbf(X,Y)

lmin=data[2].min()
lmax=data[2].max()
progn=(lmax-lmin)/20
limit=np.arange(lmin,lmax,progn)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2)) #x ranges between 3 to 57, y -1 to -10
ax.contour(X,Y,Z,limit) 
ax.set_title('Contour Plot')
plt.show()
```

With the above code this plot is derived.

[image: 1]

However, it is not desired and if once can see through the surfacial noise lines then there are ordered contour lines underneath, which actually is desired as seen from the contour plot generated by surfer here.

[image: 2]

I'd like to reiterate that the same data was used in generating the surfer plot.

Any help in creating the desired plot shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way is to use `ax.tricontour(x, y, z, levels=np.linspace(lmin, lmax, 20))` for isolines.  Or `tricontourf` for colored regions. Those functions work on 3 arrays that don't need to be organized as a 2D grid. Note that `X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)` doesn't work for your data.

Comment: To see how the data points are distributed, you can do scatter plot of the original data, `ax.scatter(x,y,z,s=0.1)`. It is possible that the points are already well-organized. You may only need to `reshape()` the data and are ready to create contour without doing `meshgrid` and `interpolate`.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC for your suggestion. `tricontour/tricontourf` seems to do the trick, however, without extrapolation the contours does not fill the complete plot as shown in the figures above. The contour triangularly projects downwards in the 2d frame. Can you suggest interpolation for complete contour fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JohanC for the answer. I'd like to put his suggestion to perspective with my query.

`ax.contour` replaced by `ax.tricontour` solves my situation. And `ax.tricontourf` gets the contour fill done. Therefore, the last segment of my code would be:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2)) #x ranges between 3 to 57, y -1 to -10
ax.tricontour(X,Y,Z,limit) 
ax.tricontourf(X,Y,Z,limit) 
ax.set_title('Contour Plot')
plt.show()
```

Comment: you should accept your answer if the problem is solved, this helps to filter question as solved :)

Comment: Thank you @Ruli for your recommendation. I have accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue working with irregularly spaced data on top of that loss of missing data. The suggestion made by someone about a 2D scatter plot is the perfect solution.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(df.doy,df[i].UT,c=df[i].TEC,s=10,cmap="jet")
plt.colorbar()
```

Likewsie, I plotted the same contour plot using `plt.tricontourf` and got the same result

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.tricontourf(df.doy,df.UT,df.TEC,100,cmap="jet")
plt.colorbar()
```